# Bluetooth scan returns nothing

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am recently learning Android. I tried to implement the function that searches for Bluetooth devices. I am able to list all the previously paired devices, but I am not able to discover new devices.

Permissions are set in AndroidManifest.xml.

Here is my code:

```
public void listDiscoverableDevices(boolean status) {
    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    mArrayAdapter.clear();
    mDisplay.setText("Search");
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            //BluetoothDevice.
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mArrayAdapter.add(device.getAddress());
            } else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                //mDisplay.setText(action);
                mArrayAdapter.add(action);
            } else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                //mDisplay.setText(action);
                mArrayAdapter.add(action);
            }
        }
    };

    // Register the BroadcastReceiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy

    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()) {
    mDisplay.setText("Discover failed!");
    }
}
```

It seems to me that the BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND action is never received. I have been struggling with this for two days. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It took me two days. Today I finally found out that why my program didn't work the first time. Starting from Android 6.0, you also need either `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission to scan for remote Bluetooth devices.

And you may need to go to "Settings"->"Apps"->yourApp->"Permissions" to turn on the location service permission. Or I guess you can also request the permission programmatically.